Making parentheses in the simplest way possible
I looked at some community posts asnwering how to use brackets in chemfig, but it was only for their specific case and looked very overcomplicated for what I´m trying to do.
Here is a picture of what I´m trying to do (this is the formula for PLA if you´re wondering):

Here is my current code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\scalebox{1.5}{
\chemfig{CH3-[:33]C(-[:90]CH3)(-[:-33]C(=[:-90]O)((-[:33]O(-[:-33]))))}
}

\end{document}



If you could help, thank you very much!

Hello, could this help https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Brackets_and_Parentheses

Or page 47 of the chemfig manual.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \scalebox{1.5}{
        \chemfig{H_3C-[@{op,0.5}:33]C(-[:90]CH_3)(-[:-33]C(=[:-90]O)((-[:33]O(-[@{cl,0.5}:-33]))))}
        \polymerdelim[delimiters ={[]}, height = 45pt, depth = 45pt, indice = \!n]{op}{cl}
    }
\end{document}


